# Same application pool, but multiple projects and large .dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, optimization

I've tried searching here, but could not find a answer to my question (I apologize if I missed it).

Let me set the stage. I have a solution with two sites and two class libraries

- (ClassLibrary) CommonFoo
- (ClassLibrary) SiteFooLib (has referense to CommonFoo)
- (Site) SiteFoo (has referense to CommonFoo and SiteFooLib)
- (Site) AdminFoo (has referense to CommonFoo)

The sites are using their own Application Pool (lets call them SiteFooPool and AdminFooPool).

I'm also using a external library, EO.Pdf (EssentialObjects PDF) that is currently references in SiteFoo only, for generating PDF files. But in the future AdminFoo might also need it.

My question is this, will the SiteFooPool grow in memory if I move EO.Pdf to CommonFoo? Or will it remain the same since it still in the same application pool, even if SiteFooLib also references CommonFoo?

I know the AdminFooPool will grow in memory.

Thanks, Seke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mere reference to the external DLL by itself will not cause the application pool to keep growing in memory. The memory growth of the application pool depends on what you do with that external DLL in the new site. If the new site is performing extensive operations with that DLL, then sure its app pool size will grow by a factor propotional to the memory consumed by those operations.